# android - how to get a callback when camera is either opened or closed

Tags: android, camera

one of my app shows info on the lock screen itself. Its a layer ontop of the lock screen.  I need to know when the camera is opened so i can hide it. It just like facebook messenger how it has those heads that float. i have floating imagine on the lock screen though.  i just need a call back to know when a app has opened the camera so i can hide my imagine and show it again when the camera is closed.

on SO i found this code:

```
public boolean isCameraUsebyApp() {
Camera camera = null;
try {
    camera = Camera.open();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    return true;
} finally {
    if (camera != null) camera.release();
}
return false;
```

}

the problem is this is not real time. i have to invoke this. i rather get a system call back when the camera is opened so i can hide things that may already be showing.

Comment: I forgot about the callback that you mentioned on `CameraManager` (in my now-deleted answer). Note that this is only for the Camera2 API, and so is only available on API Level 21+. Also, it only works while you have a process running. And, frankly, I'm not happy that this callback exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no system broadcast for opening/closing camera events. However, you can use android `UsageStatsManager` to check foreground application in a background service and take action when a camera application is opened, that's how most of the AppLock applications detect it.

Comment: How does it know what is a camera app? Do i Have to supply a package name?

Comment: You can create a Camera image picker intent and get package names by resolving it.